How do add esbuild to my vscode extension?
My extension requires esbuild in order to import ts files from the user's workspace but esbuild can't be bundled.
Adding !node_modules/esbuild to my .vscodeignore file did not work.
Is there a way to use the user's installed esbuild folder or is there another way?

I was able to fix it by moving 'esbuild' from devDependencies to dependencies.
